# Getting error in vertica:Function catalog.btrim(int) dose not exist, or permission is denied for catalog.btrim(int)

Tags: vertica

I am trying to execute below query in vertica:

```
select 
case when count(*) = 0 then #{aaa} || #{bbb}
else
 trim(cast(max(ccc)+1 as intger))
end
 as ccc
from apple where aaa = #{aaa}
```

Query is getting expected results in tera but in Vertica Getting error.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Vertica docu:
https://www.vertica.com/docs/10.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/String/BTRIM.htm

`BTRIM()` removes the blank characters (by default, if not specified as the second parameter) from a passed **string**. You can't `BTRIM()` a number.

Why would you want to trim an integer, in `trim(cast(max(ccc)+1 as int**e**ger))` ? It makes no sense at all!. Teradata should complain, too.

Comment: I have already used btrim. It shows Function catalog.btrim(int) dose not exist, or permission is denied for catalog.btrim(int) on Vertica as well. I have to trim an integer because I need to receive parameter as an integer from another query to make it work.

Comment: What type is `ccc`? `max(ccc)+1` is the same numeric type as `ccc`. If `ccc` is an integer, yon don't need to do anything. If `ccc` is a `FLOAT` or a `NUMERIC` , you would either `CAST(MAX(ccc)+1 AS INTEGER)`, or use the operator `::`, like in  `(MAX(ccc)+1)::INTEGER` . If `ccc` is a string, it is either successully implicitly casted as a numeric value before adding one, or it fails. You `CAST()` to change the type, you don't `TRIM()`. And you do that only if you need to.